# Adding a class to the <li> tag of a menu

Tags: 6, routes

I need to put a class/ID on the actual li element as each link in the menu has a color-coded background when active meaning, I can't just style ".active-trail" as that will be the same color for every link.

Creating a menu and using the CSS ID or class puts the ID/class on the a element, not on the `<li>` tag.

I could write something in jQuery, but I thought there might be a way in Drupal.

The output I want would be like the following.

```
<li class="leaf myCustomClass active-trail"><a href="/trash-this" class="active" title="">Test links</a></li>
<li class="leaf myCustomClass"><a href="http://#" class="specialMenuItem first" title="">first</a></li>
<li class="leaf myCustomClass"><a href="http://#" class="specialMenuItem" title="">second</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [menu attribute](https://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module which provide functionality to set id or class for the menu item.

> This simple module allows you to specify some additional attributes
>   for menu items such as id, name, class, style, and rel.

Comment: This modules the attributes to the `<a>` tags of a menu.  I would like to add attributes to the `<li>` tag instead!  This module is nice, but it doesn't do what I need it to! :(

Comment: @SolomonClosson, then you need to create your _theme_ functions and if you have any issue, then you can ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [theme_menu_item_link()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_item_link/6)

The following is an example that I pulled from an old site:

```
function THEME_menu_item_link($link)
{
    if (empty($link['localized_options']))
    {
        $link['localized_options'] = array();
    }

    //Give this menu item a unique id
    $link['localized_options']['attributes']['id'] = 'menu-item-' . $link['mlid'];

    //Not sure if this is the cleanest method, but it should allow us to follow
    //the active-trail across menu items, based on path.

    //Get the start of the current path (e.g. admin/build/modules would be admin)
    $base_path = preg_replace('/^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\/(.*)/', '${1}', drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']));

    //Get the current link we're looking at
    $this_link = drupal_get_path_alias($link['href']);

    //If the
   if($base_path == $this_link)
   {
       $link['localized_options']['attributes']['id'] = 'menu-active-trail-' . $link['mlid'];
   }

   return l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link['localized_options']);
}
```

Comment: Again, this is adding attributes to the `<a>` tags of a menu, NOT the `<li>` tags!  I need to add attributes to the `<li>` tags of a menu!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below code to your template.php.  Reference article: http://scriptcult.com/subcategory_197/article_978-add-class-to-menu-item.htm

```
/**
 * Theme a menu link.
 */
function THEMENAME_menu_link(array $variables) {
  // Add class for li.
  $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-' . $variables['element']['#original_link']['mlid'];
  // Add class for a.
  $variables['element']['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-' . $variables['element']['#original_link']['mlid'];
  return theme_menu_link($variables);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8 you can use the [menu_link_attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_attributes) module.